# How to add dynamic select box in magento configuration file

Tags: xml, magento, configuration

I want to show dynamic select box for choose value at system configuration. I have added text box as shown in images it's simple to add text box but how can I add select box same like text box.

I have added below code to show dynamic text box:

```
<fields>
    <product_option translate="label">
                            <label>Tour Options</label>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array
                            </backend_model>
                            <frontend_model>customoptioncreater/adminhtml_system_config_form_field_additem
                            </frontend_model>
                            <sort_order>31</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Add Tour Options Item</comment>
                        </product_option>
                       </fields>
```

And create model file to render html:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of your frontendmodel

```
<frontend_model>customoptioncreater/adminhtml_system_config_form_field_additem</frontend_model>
```

There you can add JS code, like:

```
echo '<script> // YOUR CODE </script>';
```

Thats the way you can "inject" JS in your Backend to make it more dynamic